# Как в динамическом массиве присвоить значения элементов?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, память, матрицы

Нужно чтобы элементы массива равнялись нулю

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int **a;
    a = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            a[i][j] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Подумалось, что в традиционном способе, как в ответе у Mikhailo, потом надо долго освобождать память - типа

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    free(a[i]);
free(a);
```

Но если выделить память одним куском, то можно обойтись и одним удалением:

```
a = malloc(n*(sizeof(int*)+m*sizeof(int)));
for(int i = 0, ofs = n*sizeof(int*); i < n; i++)
    a[i] = (int*)((char*)a + ofs + i*m*sizeof(int));

....

free(a);
```

Ну, т.е. в выделенном куске памяти лежат сначала указатели на `n` строк, а потом сами `n` строк по `m` столбцов. Понятно, что для конкретного заданного вопроса `n==m`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выделили память только под массив *указателей*:

```
a = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
```

Но каждый указатель `a[i]` не инициализирован. Нужно еще выделить память под данные:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    a[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

Если у вас и в самом деле С и компилятор настроен компилировать код как С, а не как С++ - приведения типов наподобие вашего `(int**)` *не нужны*. Если их требует компилятор - вы работаете с С++.